# angularjs disable other checkboxes if specific checkbox checked in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

Here i like to explain my problem.

i have a list of checkbox displayed by using ng-repeat, if i checked a specific checkbox it has to disable other checkbox.

```
<label ng-repeat="specific in specifications">
       <input id="specifications_chk" value="{{specific}}" ng-model="newObject[specific]" type="checkbox">
       {{specific}}
</label>
```

checkbox value is getting from json file.

[image]

Here if i check `IndepthHomeCleaning,` i need to disable others. thats it

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this, some better than others but using what you've provided this may help:

```
<label ng-repeat="specific in specifications">
   <input id="specifications_chk" value="{{specific}}" ng-model="newObject[specific]" type="checkbox" ng-disable="newObject.IndepthHomeCleaning">
   {{specific}}
</label>
```

Of course this isn't dynamic. However if you need it to always be the first specification, you could use this expression in `ng-disabled` instead:

```
ng-disable="newObject[specifications[0]]"
```

Here is a JS Fiddle example which disables all but the first checkbox if the first checkbox is checked:

https://jsfiddle.net/mLj5Lpwz/

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments it sounds like this needs to be more dynamic. You'll need to capture this data somewhere in your objects.

I've created another example which has `$scope.specifications` as an array of objects. The objects include an an `ExcludedBy` property which has which other specification will cause that specification to be disabled.

It's difficult to explain but I hope this updated example will help you achieve what you need:

https://jsfiddle.net/mLj5Lpwz/3/

Comment: No..the specification which we getting here is based on service we change, this specfications is getting for the service "Home Cleaning", what if the service is Carpentry, so we can't disable specifications[0]. i hope you understand @anierzad

Comment: @Nodemon I think I understand what you need and I've updated my answer with some additional explanation and a further example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the solution to your problem
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anshulbisht06/mLj5Lpwz/2/